# Error Message "HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns..."

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I ran this in AWS Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nina-nba-database`.`nina_nba_test` (
  `Data` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1',
  'input.regex' = 'nina'
) LOCATION 's3://nina-gray/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

However when I try to select the table using the syntax below:

```
SELECT * FROM "nina-nba-database"."nina_nba_table" limit 10;
```

It gives me this error:

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
This query ran against the "layla-nba-database" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: b96e4344-5bbe-4eca-9da4-70be11f8e87d

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the input.regex serde property?

Answer (score 1):

The input.regex in your query doesn't look like valid one. The specified regex group while creating the table becomes a new column. So if you want to read data inside a column as new column you can specify the valid regex, to understand more about regex you can refer to Regex SerDe examples from this aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-ug.pdf). Or if your use case to just read columnar data you can create the table specifying proper delimiter, For example if your data is comma separated you can specify the delimiter as

```
...
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
...
```

have a look at this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html) for more details.